# FormatException on Html.DisplayFor for decimal values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

My model has a `DisplayFormat` set as shown in image below

```
[BsonElement("spread")]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128,AllowTruncation =true)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{N6}")]
public decimal Spread { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the following code:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Entries.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Entries[i].Spread)
            </td>
```

Still, when the page loads, I get the error:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>       System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()
>       System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, string format, ParamsArray args)
>       string.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, string format, ParamsArray args)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TemplateBuilder.Build()
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.GenerateDisplay(ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string htmlFieldName, string templateName, object additionalViewData)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperDisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression> expression)
>       AspNetCore._Views_Dashboard_Bordao_cshtml+d__30.MoveNext() in Bordao.cshtml
>       +
>                           @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Entries[i].Spread)

I tried changing the `formatString` to `"0.000"`, `"N6"`.. Still no success..
If outside the view code I run `string.format(spread, "N6")`, I get the correct result.

How can I get my view to format my decimal values with 6 decimal places.
Thanks

Comment: But, according to the screenshot, the error seems to be coming from the `Spread` property

Comment: Your code should work fine without any issues regarding the formatting you applied to `InitialBalance` property. Are you sure that is the cause of the issue ? Looking at the screenshot, it is a different property!. Also do not post images of code, post the relevant part of code itself to the question.

Comment: sorry for the image posting. The Spread property is configured the same way.

Comment: edited to change images for code

Comment: Its needs to be `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N6}")]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are absolutely right. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know why N6 does not work. Got it working with 6 decimal places using

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.#######}")]
```

or

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N6}")]
```